# Switching a div on click using ReactJS

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I have come with a problem of switching a div on clicking a written text on a kind of a toggle-bar or something.

Basically, I am recreating a WordPress website template, using React JS. The template is originally built on bootstrap.[THIS](http://demo.themewinter.com/html/exhibz/index.html) is the template.

So I have done all the parts using simple HTML and CSS and rendered the sections using reacts class method,(but I plan to change them to function as I am not dealing with state). I completed all the sections this way but now I have a section(get directions to event hall section, *the second last section*) here that has a kind of nav-bar that animates and switches the represented data and also changes the active heading along with a small pointer thingy below it. I am attaching a picture of it also:

[image: Pointing out the bar]

Currently, and by default it is at **Venue**, but on clicking either of **Time** or **How to get there** it switches the pink pointer underneath them and also changes its size accordingly, and when clicked at either of these, it animates and switches the stuff underneath it *(at least that's what it is supposed to do, they have added the same text in all three*).

How can I achieve all this switching and retaining the currently active heading?
Here's my code specifically for this part:

```
import React,{Component} from 'react'

class Directions extends Component{
    render(){
        return(
            <section id = "Directions-section">
                <div id = "directions-div">
                    <div id="directions-text">
                        <div id ="d-img">
                            <img style={{position:"relative",top:"60px"}} src="http://demo.themewinter.com/html/exhibz/images/shap/Direction_memphis3.png" 
                            alt=''/>
                        </div>
                        <div id="d-t">
                            <div id="htgt">
                                <h1>
                                    <span>REACH US</span>
                                    Get Direction to the <br />Event Hall<br/>
                                    <img src="http://demo.themewinter.com/html/exhibz/images/shap/title.png"
                                    alt=''/>
                                </h1>
                            </div>
                            <div id="toggle">
                                <div id="toggle-header">
                                    <ul>
                                        <li className="active">Venue</li>
                                        <li>Time</li>
                                        <li>How to get there</li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                                <div id="toggle-address">
                                    <h2>
                                        Brighton Waterfront Hotel, Brighton, London
                                        <span>
                                        1Hd- 50, 010 Avenue, NY 90001<br/>
                                        United States
                                        </span>
                                    </h2>
                                </div>
                                <div id="toggle-info">
                                    <div id="tickets-info">
                                        <h2>Tickets info</h2>
                                        <h2>Name: <span>Ronaldo König</span></h2>
                                        <h2>Phone: <span>009-215-5595</span></h2>
                                        <h2>Email: <span>info@example.com</span></h2>
                                    </div>
                                    <div id="programme-Details">
                                        <h2>Programme Details</h2>
                                        <h2>Name: <span>Ronaldo König</span></h2>
                                        <h2>Phone: <span>009-215-5595</span></h2>
                                        <h2>Email: <span>info@example.com</span></h2>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
              </section>
         )
        }
```

This is the code for one of the divs only and I plan on copying it three times, one for each heading and apply the method you suggest.

The CSS for this:

```
#Directions-section
{
    position: relative;
    top:320px;
    width:100%;
    height:600px;
}

#directions-div
{
    position: absolute;
    top:0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}

#directions-text
{
    flex:1;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}

#d-img{flex: 1;}

#d-t
{
    flex:5;
    width:100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    padding: 20px;
}

#htgt
{
    flex: 1;
    width: 100%;
}

#htgt h1
{
    font-size: 36px;
    font-weight: 800;
    color: #3b1d82;
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    line-height: 1.2;
}

#htgt span
{
    display: block;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: #888888;;
}

#toggle
{
    flex:2;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

#toggle-header
{
    flex: 1;
    width: 100%;
}

#toggle-header ul li
{
    display: inline-block;
    list-style: none;
    margin-right:50px;
    color: #888888;
    font-family: 'Roboto',sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 700;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #cccaca;
}

#toggle-header li:visited
{
    color: #e7015e;
    border-color: #e7015e;
}

#toggle-header li .active
{
    color: #e7015e;
    border-color: #e7015e;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#toggle-address
{
    flex:1;
    width:100%;
}

#toggle-address h2
{
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #1c1c24;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;
}

#toggle-address span
{
    display: block;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #888888;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-weight: normal;
}

#toggle-info
{
    flex:3;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}

#tickets-info
{
    flex: 1;
    width: 100%;
}

#tickets-info h2
{
    font-family: 'Roboto',sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #222222;
}

#tickets-info span
{
    color: #888888;
}

#programme-Details
{
    flex: 1;
    width: 100%;
}

#programme-Details h2
{
    font-family: 'Roboto',sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #222222;
}

#programme-Details span
{
    color: #888888;
}
```

**P.S:** I did not include Bootstrap, because of a small misunderstanding and when I included it at a later stage, it messed up the hard work of a month!

**Edit:** I also need to change the text down below on clicking a different heading and add animation that shows the text changing.

Comment: Practically each tab need to have its own index value. And you need to store this value in the state in order to react can follow your clicks.

Comment: It looks like you have three components (venue, time and directions) and may want to use react-router-dom package. Using NavLink component will handle active link as well.

Comment: @Hyetigran thanks for giving me time but unfortunately I don't know React-Router, I only know classes, function or the useState Hook

Comment: @Ozzie A little more explanation could be more helpful, where to put the indices and how to, stupid me but I am a beginner!

Comment: create a new component for the venue, time, and how to get there, and for the section component just use props.children.....now you can change the component by onclick listener by checking the condition based on some key/id for each component....also assign the active class to that header which is clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to switch this ul with yours

```
 <ul>
            {["Venue","Time","How to get there"].map((e,i) => 
            <li onClick={() => this.setState({selected: i})} 
          className={this.state.selected === i ?"active":null}>{e}</li>)}
         </ul>
```

and

add this above the `render()` method

```
state = { 
        selected:0
     }
```

Comment: Sorry it did nothing except display the headings!
Plus I also need to animate the text below and show different text on clicking different headings!

Comment: I checked the google dev tools console, this is what I get: Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.

Comment: you can add key={i} before onClick for that